# Adjacency Map - How to remove a edge from a Graph

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, graph

I'm in this problem for hours, because I can't find a method that can remove the edges from a adjacency map graph in O(1) time.

If anyone has any idea, it would be very helpful.

Comment: How about HashMap?

Comment: I think this is like an HashMap, because he have the keys and the values on them. The problem is that, I don't know how to remove an edge from all dictionary keys that he might be in. For example, we have this dictionary : dic = {1: [e,i,o], 2: [p,i,e], 3:[u,e,m]}. How can I remove the value "e" in O(1) time?

Comment: So you have multiple edges with label "e"? (from 1 to 1, and between 2 and 3)?

Comment: Do you have to use a map? You could use a sparse matrix, then you can set the edge entry to `0`. On the other hand, inserting new edges is really slow if you cannot bulk insert them. You may even consider a dense matrix (the easiest choice) when memory is no problem, what is true for many meshes.

Comment: @trincot this was a bad example, sorry. This is example I think is better, dic = {1: [e], 2: [e,u], 3:[u]}. So, in here we have from 1 to 2 and from 2 to 3. (View this as an undirected graph)

Comment: @JoãoJúlio wait are you trying to remove Node or Edge?

Comment: Then I think you should create a second data structure from it, keyed by those edge labels: `{"e": [1, 2], "u": [2, 3]}`. And the existing one should have sets as values, instead of lists. You need to keep those two updated in tandem, but it will allow O(1).

Comment: @trincot creat another data structure inside the Graph data structure? I understand what you are trying to say, but how is this going to work in the adjacency map? If we are creating a sparated data structure, the main data structure is not goin to change (In this case, **bold** {1: [e], 2: [e,u], 3:[u]})

Comment: @allo Yes, the adjacency matrix is way easier to implement (in my opinion). I'm asking this because it's an exercise from my data structures and algorithms course.

Comment: @JoãoJúlio I think doing this in `O(1)` is only possible for special cases. A Hashmap is one possibility, but you need to be aware that a Hashmap will be resized at some point (`O(n)`) when you continue inserting edges.

Answer (score 1):

You should have HashMap (or dict in python) with Keys some kind of Node-index and Values to be for example HashSet (or set in python) of Node-indexes, edges from given Key node reach to.
For example `{1: {2, 3}, 2: {1, 3}, 3: {1}}` means, you have 3 nodes: `1, 2, 3` and eges are: `[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 3], [3, 1]` - assuming it's directed graph. If you want to remove edge let's say 2, 3, obtain key (starting node of the edge) from your hashmap in O(1) time:
something like `graph.get(2)` which will return you your value - hashSet of Nodes edges lead to, in this case `{1, 3}`. From this set, you can remove 3 (end node) again in O(1) time.

Repeat this process for all edges you may have.

Comment: This answer is correct, but uses a completely non-Pythonic terminology and notations. `HashMap` and `HashSet` are not found in Python, and the literal value you used for the adjacency map is made to look like a set of lists, which is impossible to create in Pyhton - the syntax is legal, but lists cannot be stored in sets. Please edit this to Python conventions.

Comment: @Ecto thanks for answer! the problem is that I don't understand that terminology.... because I only know python

Comment: @JoãoJúlio sorry about that, I have tried to write it in python (which I don't know too much about), take a peek https://textuploader.com/1cltv

Comment: @Ecto I don't understand what you are trying to do with that code. Thanks for your help and time!!!!

Comment: @JoãoJúlio removing an edge from a graph in O(1) time

Comment: @Ecto I don't think it works in python, at least with the data structure that I'm building. Because that code is basically removing only from graph[2] and we want to remove from all keys (Correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: @JoãoJúlio edge leads only from one node, therefore it shouldn't be necessary to remove from other keys

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213579/discussion-between-joao-julio-and-ecto).

Answer (score 1):

To remove a vertex `v` from an adjacency map `G`, you would need to access all `u` such that there exists an edge `(u, v)`.

Alternative to the other solution proposed by Ecto, you can keep a *reverse* graph `G_reverse`, where all the edges are reversed. So, for each edge `(u, v)`, you can have `(v, u)` in this secondary adjacency map. Then, when you wish to remove all edges from `G` that connect `v` to some other node `u`, you can simply look into `G_reverse[v]`, which would contain all the vertices `u` that have an outgoing edge to `v` in `G`.

Below is a sample implementation of the concept I described.

```
def remove(G, G_reverse, v):
    for u in G_reverse:
        del G[u][v] // Remove the incoming edges

    for u in G[v]:
        del G_reverse[u][v] // Delete reverses of the outgoing edges

    del G[v] // Removes the outgoing edges
    del G_reverse[v] // Remove the reverses of the incoming edges
```

As a final note, you may want to change the title and the description of your question to better reflect the problem. What you want seems to be the removal of all edges relevant to a particular vertex, so that each such edge is removed in `O(1)` time. Unfortunately the question text does not actually reflect that, and it may be misleading to people who will be searching for similar answers here.